# I am creating a recurring number generator and I keep getting a ValueError

Tags: python, numbers

I keep getting a ValueError for this code. Can someone help me out here?

```py
f = open('perrin.txt','a')
perrinv.append(perrin(value))
perrinfd[(int(str(perrin(value))[0]))-1] += 1
rfd = [perrinfd[x]/sum(perrinfd) for x in range(0,9)]
error = sum([abs(rfd[x]-benFreqs[x]) for x in range(0,9)])
f.write(str(error)+'\n')
f.close()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 107, in <module>
    perrinfd[(int(str(perrin(value))[0]))-1] += 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In the future please supply the functions that you used so we can try to recreate the error.
My best is is that in this line:
`perrinfd[(int(str(perrin(value))[0]))-1] += 1`, `perin(value)` returns a negative number (lets say `-10.2`). Then, converting to a string and taking the first letter gives `-`. Then you try and convert this back to an int, which is clearly not possible (this is what the error is saying).

I am not sure what the functions do and what you are trying to achieve with that line, but pick one of the following fixes based on what you would like the behaviour to be:

- First call abs() to ignore/remove the negative
- troubleshoot perin()
- Perhaps check the sign then add it in after converting back to an integer

Answer (score 0):

Check the "perrin.txt", seems like `str(perrin(value))[0]` it's "-", so it gives you an error because it's not an integer number and you are trying to use `int()` on it